# Import error in Magento2 admin

Tags: magento2, product, url-key, product-import

I am importing product with csv file of 200 products.

Two product have same name, so when in import i am getting below error.

```
 Url key: 'key' was already generated for an item with the SKU: '39921'. You need to specify the unique URL key manually
```

How can i suppress this error, can we not create the product with same name with url key is different?

I need to import product with same name for both the products.

How this can be done? Please anyone suggest me

Comment: You need specify the unique url key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now typical of Magento 2 import.

there are 2 scenarios:

- the url key that exists is from the same product but somehow conflicts with the product to add/update
- the url key conflicts with another sku that has the same name in your csv file

The second is likely your issue, I suggest to write a script that reads your csv file and add a suffix to the names that appears in duplicate. Often with Magento 1, that is the case for children products from a configurable. So your may add the option value to the name so that child products url key become fine for import in Magento 2

If you happen to find the first scenario is in your way, you may have to write a small customisation that removes the url key for the sku before a sku gets imported in Magento 2